# Accumulator factory in Haskell

Tags: haskell, stateful

Now, at the start of my adventure with programming I have some problems understanding basic concepts. Here is one related to Haskell or perhaps generally functional paradigm.

Here is a general statement of accumulator factory problem, from
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Accumulator_factory

> [Write a function that]
>
> - Takes a number n and returns a function (lets call it g), that takes a number i, and returns n incremented by the accumulation of i from every call of function g(i).
> - Works for any numeric type-- i.e. can take both ints and floats and returns functions that can take both ints and floats. (It is not enough simply to convert all input to floats. An accumulator that has only seen integers must return integers.) (i.e., if the language doesn't allow for numeric polymorphism, you have to use overloading or something like that)
> - Generates functions that return the sum of every number ever passed to them, not just the most recent. (This requires a piece of state to hold the accumulated value, which in turn means that pure functional languages can't be used for this task.)
> - Returns a real function, meaning something that you can use wherever you could use a function you had defined in the ordinary way in the text of your program. (Follow your language's conventions here.)
> - Doesn't store the accumulated value or the returned functions in a way that could cause them to be inadvertently modified by other code. (No global variables or other such things.)

with, as I understand, a key point being:
"[...] creating a function that [...]
Generates functions that return the sum of every number ever passed to them, not just the most recent. (This requires a piece of state to hold the accumulated value, which in turn means that pure functional languages can't be used for this task.)"

We can find a Haskell solution on the same website and it seems to do just what the quote above says.

Here
http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Haskell
it is said that Haskell is purely functional.

What is then the explanation of the apparent contradiction? Or maybe there is no contradiction and I simply lack some understanding? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Haskell solution does not actually quite follow the rules of the challenge. In particular, it violates the rule that the function "Returns a real function, meaning something that you can use wherever you could use a function you had defined in the ordinary way in the text of your program." Instead of returning a real function, it returns an `ST` computation that produces a function that itself produces more `ST` computations. Within the context of an `ST` "state thread", you can create and use mutable references (`STRef`), arrays, and vectors. However, it's impossible for this mutable state to "leak" outside the state thread to contaminate pure code.

Comment: I would argue that the rules of the problem violate the definition of the term “function”, so Haskell is perfectly entitled to violate those rules.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, I completely agree with you.